# Django queryset filter by multi percentage wildcard

Tags: python-3.x, django

I know that Django queryset has `contains`, `startswith` and `endswith` to perform LIKE operation like `%word%`, `%word` and `word%`.

Is there any way to perform like operation `%w%o%r%d%`?

Comment: It's better to write [**`Func`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expressions in such cases

Answer (score 0):

I case you're lazy and don't want to write a Func, use [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/):

```
queryset = Model.objects.raw("SELECT some, field WHERE a_field LIKE '%w%o%r%d%'")[start:limit]
```